# Finding the cause for waiting/sleeping threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I noticed that my java application (runs on tomcat6) spawns a lot of threads which do not terminate.

So I created a thread dump and noticed that there are tons of threads waiting, like this:

```
"pool-1-thread-22" prio=5 tid=101b4b000 nid=0x127122000 waiting on condition [127121000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <6c340cee0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Now the question is: WHAT are these threads waiting for?
I have suspect class which seems to spawn these threads but I don't know what exactly is making these threads stuck.

Is there anything I can do to find the cause for this except for tearing the class apart line by line and keep monitoring thread behavior?

Comment: Um, they're blocking on a queue. Specifically, `LinkedBlockingQueue.take()` which blocks indefinitely when a queue is empty.

Comment: What does that mean? What queue and what does that method `take()` do?

Comment: Erm, it's your code ... we're not psychic. Just telling you exactly what the thread dump is telling you.

Comment: ? I didn't write java.util.* for sure.

Comment: You have a thread. It's using a blocking queue. That queue is empty. Your thread is blocking trying to read from it because it is empty. It will block there forever unless something is added to the queue. We can not see your code. Without your code no one can help you beyond that.

Comment: Mh, I just understood that `Collection implements LinkedBlockingQueue` so it's possible that a list or other collection is trying to call `take()` but it can't (for some reason) and thus the thread is blocked.. right?

Comment: @BrianRoach You already helped me a lot. I think I'll go hunt for an empty collection in those threads.

Comment: @valmar take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem.  Threads will sit on the queue until there is an item on the queue available.  If there is no item on the queue the thread will sit and wait until another thread places the item on the queue.

Comment: @JohnVint Thanks for that link. It looks like I forgot a synchronized{} statement somewhere in my code.

Comment: In my case, I made an error that caused `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());` to get called for every web request. This created new thread pools, WAITING, until tomcat dies.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On tomcat, they're usually request worker threads waiting for someone to connect.
Nothing to worry about. They're ready to handle those 100 users connecting at once to your server.

Comment: That can't be. I can explicitly click a button in my application that spawns these threads. Once clicked, these threads appear. After a while these threads consume so much memory that the server crashes.

Comment: If a thread is blocked, (eg. waiting on a queue), they cannot consume any more memory - they are not running and so cannot request any.  If anything, their stacks may well get paged out after waiting a while and so actually reduce real RAM use.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @ptyx on this. Presumably clicking a button in your application sends a requests to the Tomcat server. My guess is that you have a bad configuration telling Tomcat to be able to handle an obscenely large number of requests because you want to be enterprisey. Tomcat keeps making a new `Thread` in its `ThreadPoolExecutor` because it hasn't reached `corePoolSize`. Ultimately crashing your server because you have configured for a large number of threads but not allowed for enough memory to allocate all the stack space needed for those threads. But that is just my guess.

Comment: Yes, I've set `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3000);` because otherwise the application will crash when this number of threads has been reached. Thus I want to find the reason why those threads do not terminate so I can reduce that number.

Comment: That's it! I reduced the pool size and now tomcat seems to "recycle" pooled threads properly and does not spawn that insanely high number of threads. Thanks, Tim!

Answer (score 6):

Those threads are part of a ThreadPool.  More specificaly java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.  The thread is waiting on a Runnable/Callable to be submitted to the pool.  For example

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Will create 10 threads that will sit an wait until

```
e.submit(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){ ...}
});
```

Then one thread will be notified and invoke that runnable.  What they are being used for I cannot tell.  You'll have to find out what started the thread pool.  Maybe its handling client requests to the application server.

Comment: Don't think so. These threads are not fixed. They're created dynamically when the user interacts with the application. After long usage there are hundreds of them, not just 10.

Comment: I guess you'll have to find out what happens after the user interacts.  Anyone can create these threads as you see in my example.  If you get us more code of what is happening we can help.